# Tomcat app on the Mac

Tags: macos, jsp, tomcat

I inherited a Tomcat project and i'm trying to get it set up to do some local dev/testing on my Mac. I've set up one before and got it working fine, but this one's folder structure is slightly different. There's only "includes" and "WEB-INF" folders at the root. When i place those folders in my Tomcat ROOT folder, I keep getting a 404 error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, like what logs to look at, etc.

[UPDATE]

So this is the top of the web.xml file in the WEB-INF folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4" xmlns="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"; xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">;
```

So does that mean i put this app in webapps/WebApp_9 ? And when i'm trying to view the site in a browser, so i use this URL localhost:8080/WebApp_9  ( put the app in a folder also named WebApp_9).

I still get a 404 when i go to that URL.

Comment: What url gave you the 404, what did you expect to find on that url and why? (Look for a web.xml under the WEB-INF folder, that might specify some servlet mappings that you can request)

Comment: You don't place your stuff under `webapps/ROOT` but under `webapps/yourAppName`

Comment: Ok, newbie here. So this is the top of the web.xml file in the WEB-INF folder.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  

So does that mean i put this app in webapps/WebApp_9 ?   And when i'm trying to view the site in a browser, so i use this URL http://localhost:8080/WebApp_9/ ?

Comment: @user412 Insted of posting code in comment update your with it.

Comment: Sorry, just updated the post with the code sample.